# How to insert a UIImage into an e-mail with html content?

Tags: html, uiimage, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm sending mails thanks to the MFMailComposeViewController API, and I manage to add uiimages in attachment, but I'd like to insert my uiimage into html code in my e-mail, any idea of what kind of conversion I should use for my image ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the image into PNG (`UIImagePNGRepresentation`) or JPEG (`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`) data.

Then, call [`-addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-SW2) on the mail compose view controller with that PNG/JPEG data.

Your image will be shown as an attachment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now, but actually I would like to have my image directly in html code inside the body of the mail, not as an attachment...

Comment: @Yoot: Unfortunately, there's no documented way to get the Content-ID of that attached image. Maybe you could try `data:` URI scheme...